# Is it possible to deploy an exploded war file to JBoss 4.2.3?

Tags: intellij-idea, war, jboss-4.2.x

I'm trying to use IntelliJ to deploy exploded wars to JBoss 4.2.3.  I seem to have no problem with doing this with 5.0.1.

But when I switch the server to 4.2.3, IntelliJ tells me that the extension for the exploded war is invalid, which makes very little sense, given that it is an exploded war.  It seems to be expecting a .war file extension.

It seems that JBoss 4.2.3 can only take compressed war files, though I haven't found documentation to prove it.

Is there a way to configure JBoss 4.2.3 to accept exploded wars?

Comment: JBoss 4 will accept exploded WAR directories just fine. It seems to be IntelliJ at fault here. Try giving the directory name the .war extension.

Comment: JBoss 5.0.1 doesn't require that....why does JBoss 4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JBoss 4.x requires the exploded directory to have `.war` in the end of its name, adjust IDEA artifact settings and it will work fine.

Comment: Macs don't seem to accept a .war as part of the directory name.  Any ideas for a Mac?

Comment: The artifact output directory name can be typed in manually in the text field, you don't have to use the file chooser.

Comment: The IDEA error message is not friendly at all, is there any open issue about this?